# Is there need to remove breakpoint ipa file to run on Ad hoc/Development/app store ipa file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What happened if i didn't remove breakpoint while ipa run on

1.Device(for Development)

2.Ad-Hoc build

3.App Store ipa submission.

Does it stop running due to breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it stop running due to breakpoint?

**No.**

Breakpoint works only when you run a project/app from Xcode.

If you use build i.e. ipa(iOS) or app(osx) then breakpoint doesn't effect.

Breakpoints are generally used to debug and fix through Xcode whether you use simulator or device. Once the binary is generated the breakpoint gets discarded.

Comment: @AvijitNagare: Nope. If you want to debug, then you can use Logs. There are multiple logging tools available as...Lumberjack, DDLog.